# How to set the src of an iframe to the current visited site using java script?

Tags: javascript, iframe, web

I would like to take a snapshot of the current visited site at a fixed resolution independent of client web-browser resolution.
Therefor I would like to load the active site in an hidden iframe with that fixed resolution and take the snapshot from there.

Now my question is: How can I load the same site I am currently on in an iframe. Loading other pages works fine, but yet I was not able to load the same site in the iframe.

Is this some security issue?

Comment: That will create an endless loading loop. You load the current page into the iframe, which in turn loads the current page into *its* iframe, and so on...

Comment: Unless you check if you r in iframe `window.top !== window.window`.

Answer (score 1):

Tested the nested iframe, where its `.src` is equal to `document.href.url` in different browsers. Only Chrome allows such iframe embedded in the first level, other browsers prevent the above described recursion and leave the iframe empty. (As a side note, also it looks like Firefox and Opera allow at most 10 respectively 20 different nested iframes, other browsers like Google Chrome and Explorer add iframes ad infinitum.) You can use the following code to embed the parent page in the iframe, via the slightly modified url:

```js
function load_iframe(addr) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1');
    if (addr == document.location.href) {
        if (addr.indexOf('?') == -1) {
            addr += '?dummy_string';
        } else {
            addr += '&dummy_string';
        }
    }
    iframe.src = addr;
}
```

HTML example:

```html
<a href="" onclick="event.preventDefault();load_iframe(this.href);">This page</a>
<iframe id="frame1" src="" style="width:100%; height:500px" />
```

[The test script is here.](http://pastebin.com/MURfud8M)

Comment: Thanks to all respondents for the quick advices. I followed the suggestion of Stano. This works fine for me and is exactly what i wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

> if (!document.getElementById('hiddenFrame') {
>   document.appendChild('<iframe id="hiddenFrame"
>   src='+document.location+' style="display:none"'/>);
>   }

Place the script at the bottom of the page just before closing BODY tag, or use a library like jQuery.